# Solution to ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have searched stackoverflow thoroughly but could not find any solution to this error that i have been receiving.

Information:

1. I am using redirects only in `.htaccess` and there are no active html redirects in my webpages.
2. I am using `.htaccess` to redirect `default.php` to `root`, `non-www` to `www`, `error page 404.php`, `cache control` & `gzip` the files. (My htaccess contents are given below).

Error:

1. I typed in a wrong url to test the `404 redirect` and received a display `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`. I tried clearing browser cache and also researched on stackoverflow to debug my `htaccess` codes but got no solutions as of yet.

Help Required:

1. I would request the stackoverflow members to help me solve this error, for reference i am posting my htaccess code below.

HTACCESS:

```
<Ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

### re-direct default.php to root / ###
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*\/default\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)default\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

### re-direct non-www to www of main domain
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^bookkeralatourpackage\.in$ [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.bookkeralatourpackage.in/$1 [r=301,nc,L]

#### Rule for Error Page - 404 ####
ErrorDocument 404 http://bookkeralatourpackage.in/404.php
</Ifmodule>

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Connection keep-alive
ExpiresActive On

# Expires after 1 month
<filesMatch ".(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|ico|pdf|js|htm|html|txt)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
</filesMatch>

# Expires after 1 day
<filesMatch ".(css)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400"
</filesMatch>
</ifModule>

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

Let me know where i have gone wrong and also in case if any other detail would be required to solve this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The most obvious problem is that the error document does not have `www`. This means that after redirecting to `http://bookkeralatourpackage.in/404.php`, the `www` redirect will have to be applied.  Change it to:

  ```
  ErrorDocument 404 http://www.bookkeralatourpackage.in/404.php
  ```
- The next possible problem would be if the `404.php` file doesn't exist: you will enter a chain of redirects. So please do check if `http://www.bookkeralatourpackage.in/404.php` exists.
- I am not entire sure the `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*\/default\.php\ HTTP/` line is needed. The rule might work without it.

Please let us know if any of this works.

Comment: Thanks for your time. As per your advise i added the www yet had the same error popping up.
404.php does exist so i guessed may be giving the complete url is not necessary (i modified the code to ErrorDocument 404 /404.php) and now it works (No "too-many-redirect-error" now). Only catch here is that any errors in subfolders (pages in www.bookkeralatourpackage.in/kerala-tour/xxxx.php) do not redirect to 404.php, i am now stuck here.
I have removed the line (RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*\/default\.php\ HTTP/) and tested it doesnt work.

Thanks again for your time and help.

Comment: You are an angel. I just checked the 404.php file and also made some changes to the 'RewriteCond' line as per your lead, it works perfect now :) not sure what was causing the error. I am sharing the final htaccess code below, hope it helps someone like me. Thank you again for helping me out :)

Comment: <Ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

### re-direct default.php to root / ###
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/default\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)default.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

### re-direct non-www to www of main domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bookkeralatourpackage\.in [nc]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.bookkeralatourpackage.in/$1 [r=301,L]
####

#### Rule for Error Page - 404 ####
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

</Ifmodule>

Rest of it remains the same.

Comment: I have clicked the check mark next to the answer, thank you for guiding me on the same i am new here so your guidance does help :)